# WebView not working in Android when used with OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, webview

I am working on a simple Android App which uses WebView.

The code is:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editUrl"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/url_hint"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonGo"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/url_go"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linear1"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    WebView mWebView;
    EditText editText;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUrl);
                String url = editText.getText().toString();
                mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

However, this code doesn't seem to work. I don't know why. It was working perfectly when I did not add any EditText or Button, and the code in the **MainActivity.java** was:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                String url = "http://google.com";

                mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening because the app seemed to work fine before.
When I changed the layout, the app doesn't work.

Please help me in detail as I am new to Android.

Thanks.

**PLEASE FEEL FREE TO SUGGEST ME A BETTER METHOD TO IMPLEMENT THIS ALSO**

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: The URL typed in the EditText is not displayed in the WebView.

Comment: What exactly are you typing in the `editText` field?

Comment: I am typing the URL. Example: I open the app, I type http://google.com in the EditText and then click the GO button. Then the WebView loads the URL I typed in EditText.

Comment: See my answer below.  Your code works as-is, but you have to type in the full url.  I think my answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

Create java object of all other view objects like web view before it and then try.

Comment: Please explain this in code. I am pretty new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code as is, and it worked.  One thing to note though, you have to type in the full url, for example: `http://www.example.com`.

One improvement would be to make it so you just have to type in `example.com` by doing something like this:

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUrl);
            String url = editText.getText().toString();

            if (!url.contains("www")){
                url = "www." + url;
            }

            if (!url.contains("http")){
                url = "http://" + url;
            }

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            mWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }
    });
```